# How to convert DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized to BGR color

Tags: uwp

I am using code as per this link to capture screen frame in UWP C#(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture).

After it I use below code to get bytes from frame.

```
// Convert our D3D11 surface into a Win2D object.
                        var canvasBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(
                            _canvasDevice,
                            frame.Surface);
```

I got bytes properly but pixel format is "DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized", Now problem is that I need to pass this captured pixcel to other Audio/Video vendor API which support to BGR color format. so how can I convert this pixcel format in BGR color plate.

Thanks

Comment: Additional note : If I set any other value than "DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized" the got error System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.' error.

Comment: What value did you set and have you changed it also in setup() method?

Comment: _surface = _compositionGraphicsDevice.CreateDrawingSurface(
                new Windows.Foundation.Size(400, 400),
                DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,
                DirectXAlphaMode.Premultiplied);    // This is the only value that currently works with the composition APIs.

Comment: I have set same value as above code

Comment: Per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/understand-direct3d-11-1-concepts): "There are also not BGR equivalents to every RGB format (DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM is equivalent to D3DFMT_A2B10G10R10, but there’s no direct equivalent to D3DFMT_A2R10G10B10). "  Which means by default there is not such an API which can directly help you have the BGR format in UWP platform.